# Android Room getting substring not working

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to search a substring using room for example in string "I am eating mutton", I am trying to search "eating" as a substring, I am trying this query, it works fine if I search for exact substring "eating" but doesn't work if I search with "I am eating rice" etc.

```
@Query("select msg_temp from auto_reply where keyword LIKE '%'||:keyword||'%'")
fun selectKeyword(keyword: String): String
```

I have seen many answers, all are suggesting same method, even this query works in sqlite browser. Any help should be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :-

```
@Query("select msg_temp from auto_reply where keyword LIKE :keyword")
fun selectKeyword(keyword: String): String
```

and then use

```
selectKeyword("%eating%")
```

an alternative (but case sensitive) :-

```
@Query("select msg_temp from auto_reply where instr(keyword,:keyword)")
```

- wild characters are not considered so just `selectKeyword("eating")`

another that should work but!!!!

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE :wildchar || :name || :wildchar")
fun selectKeyword("eating","%")
```